# contact info extraction by web crawling with scrapy / python

Tags: python, regex, xcode, scrapy

I am very new to scrapy and python in general, but I really want to learn and I have given this a lot of effort! I am trying to crawl eb5info.com, select each individual regional center, and copy the phone numbers and emails from each. However, when I crawl it notified me that 0 websites were crawled. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Here is my spider:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class Eb5Item(Item):
description = Field()

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from parser_module.items import Eb5Item

class Eb5Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'eb5'
    allowed_domains = ["eb5info.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://eb5info.com/regional-centers"]
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'regional-centers/*$']), callback='parse_item'),)
    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//ul/li/a/@href')
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            item = Eb5Item()
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['phone'] = site.select("()").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return (items)
```

And here is my items file:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class Eb5Item(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    name = Field()
    email = Field()
    name = Field()
    description = Field()
    phone = Field()
    pass
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: I see you deleted your own question and reposted it. Kindly refrain from doing so, if there's no clear difference.

Comment: My apologies, being new to this website, I accidentally marked an extremely unhelpful edit as the solution to my problem and was generally concerned that my question would remain registered as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly, using `Scrapy` for this is a little too powerful. I personally would use `requests` combined with either `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup`.

In any case, here's a working version of your code. I did not bother cleaning up the results. That's up to you.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy import Item, Field
from scrapy.http import Request
import urlparse

class Eb5Item(Item):

    name = Field()
    email = Field()
    name = Field()
    description = Field()
    phone = Field()
    url = Field()

class Eb5Spider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'eb5'
    allowed_domains = ["eb5info.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://eb5info.com/regional-centers/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        sites = hxs.xpath('//ul/li/a/@href')
        for site in sites:
            yield Request(urlparse.urljoin("http://www.eb5info.com", site.extract()), callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        item = Eb5Item()
        item['url'] = hxs.xpath("//dd/a/@href").extract()
        # item[blah]...
        print item['url']
        return item
```

The way it works is `parse` gets the links from the `start_urls`. Since there's only one page (the same URL in `start_urls`) that contains all links, there's no need to use a `Rule` to follow other pages.

We override `parse` to get the links from the said page, then use `Request` to issue a callback to `parse_item`. What this means is that for every link found by `parse`, we "go into" that link and execute `parse_item` inside it.

A scrape of this level is technically easy and does not really qualify as a crawl, which means `CrawlSpider` is overkill on this level.

Note that I'm using the latest version of Scrapy, so some classes and methods are different from yours.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much by scrapy, so i am doing this using bs4, hope you will find it useful

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
def parse_link(url):
    soup_link = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
    for x in soup_link.find_all('div','col-third'):
        for y in x:
            try:
                if y.name == 'h3' or y.name == 'dl':
                    print y.get_text()
            except:pass

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://eb5info.com/regional-centers').read())
for x in soup.find_all('li','va va_child'):
    parse_link('http://eb5info.com'+x.a.get('href'))
```

this will give you all links, then you can call a function passing the url and parse it.
I you will get the text, I haven't format it to print nicely, you can now do it, I hope you get the concept. I am printing the information here you can save it and do what ever you want.

Comment: Downloading the beautiful soup package now. I'll let you know as soon as I give it a try! Thanks!

Comment: This retrieved all of the links! Thanks, I just have to figure out how to visit them and scrape the contacts. I know they are stored as such "<dd>(909)702-8889</dd>" but I'm not sure how to properly extract them.

Comment: @MontreauxRodgers the code is working now, give it a try

Comment: @Metatron- You sir are a gentleman and a scholar. It works, thanks a lot! I'm going over your work to learn how you figured this out and again, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to beautiful soup! This will definitely come in handy and I look forward to leaning more! @Hackaholic

Comment: If you need any help you can ask, we all here for help :)